# Nodejs + Mongodb login example doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was trying out the code from the site http://code.runnable.com/U108R8ihwn4m4TM5/user-creation-signup-and-login-with-express-4-and-mongodb-for-node-js and when I run

> node server.js

The following error comes

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'connect-mongo'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amitnaik01/Login/server.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

The package.json file is given below:

```
{
  "name": "ExpressApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Node.js App using express",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.2",
    "express-session": "~1.0.3",
    "express3-handlebars": "~0.5.0",
    "mongodb": "~1.4.2",
    "connect-mongo": "git+https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo.git#master",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "engine": "node >=0.6.x"
}
```

The server.js file is below

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var expressHbs = require('express3-handlebars');
var mongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname';
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession);
var mongo = require('./mongo');
var port = 8000; // for heroku you would use process.env.PORT instead

// This is a middleware that we will use on routes where
// we _require_ that a user is logged in, such as the /secret url
function requireUser(req, res, next){
  if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect('/not_allowed');
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

// This middleware checks if the user is logged in and sets
// req.user and res.locals.user appropriately if so.
function checkIfLoggedIn(req, res, next){
  if (req.session.username) {
    var coll = mongo.collection('users');
    coll.findOne({username: req.session.username}, function(err, user){
      if (user) {
        // set a 'user' property on req
        // so that the 'requireUser' middleware can check if the user is
        // logged in
        req.user = user;

        // Set a res.locals variable called 'user' so that it is available
        // to every handlebars template.
        res.locals.user = user;
      }

      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

// Use this so we can get access to `req.body` in our posted login
// and signup forms.
app.use( require('body-parser')() );

// We need to use cookies for sessions, so use the cookie parser middleware
app.use( require('cookie-parser')() );

app.use( expressSession({
  secret: 'somesecretrandomstring',
  store: new MongoStore({
    url: mongoUrl
  })
}));

// We must use this middleware _after_ the expressSession middleware,
// because checkIfLoggedIn checks the `req.session.username` value,
// which will not be available until after the session middleware runs.
app.use(checkIfLoggedIn);

app.engine('hbs', expressHbs({extname:'hbs', defaultLayout:'main.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var coll = mongo.collection('users');
  coll.find({}).toArray(function(err, users){
    res.render('index', {users:users});  
  })
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  delete req.session.username;
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/not_allowed', function(req, res){
  res.render('not_allowed');
});

// The /secret url includes the requireUser middleware.
app.get('/secret', requireUser, function(req, res){
  res.render('secret');
});

app.get('/signup', function(req,res){
  res.render('signup');
});

// This creates a new user and calls the callback with
// two arguments: err, if there was an error, and the created user
// if a new user was created.
//
// Possible errors: the passwords are not the same, and a user
// with that username already exists.
function createUser(username, password, password_confirmation, callback){
  var coll = mongo.collection('users');

  if (password !== password_confirmation) {
    var err = 'The passwords do not match';
    callback(err);
  } else {
    var query      = {username:username};
    var userObject = {username: username, password: password};

    // make sure this username does not exist already
    coll.findOne(query, function(err, user){
      if (user) {
        err = 'The username you entered already exists';
        callback(err);
      } else {
        // create the new user
        coll.insert(userObject, function(err,user){
          callback(err,user);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}

app.post('/signup', function(req, res){
  // The 3 variables below all come from the form
  // in views/signup.hbs
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password_confirmation = req.body.password_confirmation;

  createUser(username, password, password_confirmation, function(err, user){
    if (err) {
      res.render('signup', {error: err});
    } else {

      // This way subsequent requests will know the user is logged in.
      req.session.username = user.username;

      res.redirect('/');  
    }
  });
});

// This finds a user matching the username and password that
// were given.
function authenticateUser(username, password, callback){
  var coll = mongo.collection('users');

  coll.findOne({username: username, password:password}, function(err, user){
    callback(err, user);
  });
}

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  // These two variables come from the form on
  // the views/login.hbs page
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  authenticateUser(username, password, function(err, user){
    if (user) {
      // This way subsequent requests will know the user is logged in.
      req.session.username = user.username;

      res.redirect('/');
    } else {
      res.render('login', {badCredentials: true});
    }
  });
});

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

mongo.connect(mongoUrl, function(){
  console.log('Connected to mongo at: ' + mongoUrl);
  app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server is listening on port: '+port);
  });  
})
```

Is there anyway to solve this error?

Comment: Upgrade the version of connect-mongo used in your project

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, `connect-mongo` is missing from your node modules. Please install and also save it (saving it in your package.json is just good practice).

```
npm install connect-mongo --save
```

Or simply,

```
npm i --s connect-mongo
```

**Update**

`Syntax error` is bevause of old node version, please enter these commands for updating Nodejs.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode`
This is the error that I get after installing connect-mongo

Comment: This is happening because you are running old version of node, I am updating the answer for updating nodejs, please follow that.

Answer (score 0):

Install this module again .

```
npm install connect-mongo
```

Change its version to latest.

Comment: Which is the latest version of connect-mongo?

Comment: @midhunk npm install connect-mongo --save should do the trick, it will take the version automatically.

Seems you are having issue with the es6/es5 version, reading your comments.
try this module. 
require('connect-mongo/es5')

Comment: I ran that command, but now the error is coming as `SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode`.

Comment: I saw the comments, And suggested to use the ES5 Module
i.e : 
Use this line
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo/es5')(expressSession);

Comment: I added that line and when I ran it, it's saying cannot find module './src-es5'

Comment: Can u   change ur connect-mongo version to 1.0.0
i.e make sure your package.json reads 
"connect-mongo": "1.0.0"...!!

Comment: I changed the version in the package,json file but it's still showing the same error i.e cannot find module './src-es5'.

Comment: One quick hack i can suggest is 
In node modules for connect-mongo,  remove use strict and use 
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession) again.

Comment: If I include var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession) in the server.js file, it gives the error as              `const Promise = require('bluebird');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.`

Comment: Yes,
but in node-modules/connect-mongo, in JS file remove use-strict. this will help u as a quick fix.

Comment: In the node-modules/connect-mongo folder there is a es5.js and a index.js. There is no use-strict in any of those. There is another node-modules folder which contains bluebird and a mongodb folder.

Comment: if there is es5.js then connect-mongo/es5 should work.
Can u paste es5.js gist or something ??

Comment: `module.exports = require('./src-es5');` this is the only line in es5.js